# Open source web security testing tools

Tags: security-testing, web

Are there any open source solutions for testing web security vulnerabilities?  I am not looking to make my web application bullet proof since it'll be used internally at our organization.  But I'd like to test it for the bare essentials from a web security perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zed Attack Proxy from OWASP - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

And generally I would advise browsing the site to learn more about security

Metasploit community edition is free - http://www.metasploit.com/about/choose-right-edition/

Comment: Burp Suite also has a free edition http://www.portswigger.net/burp/.  The professional edition, while not free is extremely cheap compared to other comparable solutions at $299 for a license.

Comment: Good catch, I'd forgotten that one, though how I could forget a product with such a wonderful name...

Comment: The OWASP group is a great source of info.  ZAP and the WebGoat project can teach you a LOT.  Webgoat is even guided, almost like taking a class.  Once you feel comfortable with those concepts, download and explore some of the pre-packaged distros for this like BackTrack or SamuraiWTF.  Then set up a VM and see what you can do!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tools to get you started with website/web application security testing,

[OWASP ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/)

[Burpsuite](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload)

[Subgraph Vega](https://subgraph.com/vega/download/)

[Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/)

Kali Linux has a whole bunch of [pen testing tools](https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing)